# django + mod_wsgi + apache in CentOS has UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

Every time when i restart apache **manually** (by `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart`)

My project work fine for a while.

But a few days later, it will has 500 error when my code try to use `glob.iglob` like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/django/virtualenv/gplab/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/www/django/gplab/gplab/views.py", line 166, in charging_content
    for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(target_dir_path, '*')) :
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/glob.py", line 43, in iglob
    yield os.path.join(dirname, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 70, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried to auto restart apache by `crontab`, and it don't work.

Then, i check sys default encoding by `sys.getdefaultencoding()`

I get `ascii`

But i've set `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to `zh_TW.UTF-8` in `/etc/profile`, and i tried to set `HTTPD_LANG` to `zh_TW.UTF-8` in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

It don't work.

I get some value As follows

```
locale.getlocale()   # (None, None)
locale.getdefaultlocale()   # ('zh_TW', 'UTF8')
sys.getfilesystemencoding()   # UTF-8
sys.getdefaultencoding()   # ascii
```

When I use `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd force-reload`, it become

```
locale.getlocale()   # ('zh_TW', 'UTF8')
locale.getdefaultlocale()   # ('zh_TW', 'UTF8')
sys.getfilesystemencoding()   # UTF-8
sys.getdefaultencoding()   # ascii
```

It seems that set `HTTPD_LANG` to `zh_TW.UTF-8` in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` does't chenge sys default encoding under apache with mod_wsgi.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the following part of the official Django documentation.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

Comment: Yes, and CentOS doesn't have `/etc/apache2/envvars`, it use `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` to config envs. As I said, I set it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you export the environment variables? Did you look in os.environ in the Python code to see if they were present? The /etc/profile file wouldn't be used by Apache and it must be the associated init.d configuration script for Apache httpd instead. It isn't HTTPD_LANG though and needs to be LANG and LC_ALL.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/u1Qy909.png It seems os.environ already has correct LANG and LC_ALL.

Comment: Are you loading PHP into the same Apache then. If you are, it could be treading all other things and imposing its own settings.

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/WFetTZSi](http://pastebin.com/WFetTZSi) this is my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

I try to set `engine = Off` in `/etc/php.ini`, still don't work.

Comment: Any news on this? I've got exactly the same issue.